# Translate of a closed set is closed(part2)

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

Previously, I raised a question whether $$ (a+F)^c=a+F^c.$$ Jonas Meyer pointed out that it is true. After which, I was able to prove the first inclusion. The details are as follows:
let $y\in a+F^c$. Then there exists $z\in F^c$ such that $y=a+z$. We claim that $y\in(a+F)^c$. Suppose $y\notin (a+F)^c$. Then $y\in a+F$. Thus, there exists $x\in F$ such that $y=a+x$. This implies that $z=x$. Hence, $x\in F\cap F^c=\varnothing$. We obtain a contradiction. Thus, $y\in(a+F)^c$. Hence, $a+F^c \subseteq (a+F)^c$. I tried the other inclusion, but can't prove it. A help on this is very much appreciated.

juniven

Comment: Adding the related question, so they are linked for easier reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214712/translate-of-a-closed-set-is-closed

Comment: Adding the related question about the translate of an open set being open, so they are linked for easier reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956203/how-can-i-show-that-the-translate-of-an-open-set-is-open-and-that-the-translate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your first step
\[ (a+ F)^c = a + (-a) + (a+F)^c \subseteq a + \bigl((-a)+ a + F\bigr)^c = a + F^c. \]

Comment: Ahh ok...tricky. thx very much