# how can I show that the translate of an open set is open and that the translate of a closed set is closed

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $P$ be an open set of real numbers and let $C$ be an closed set of real numbers.  Let $x$ be a real number.  How can I show that $P + x$ is open and that $C + x$ is closed?

It's been a while since I worked with topology and I'm sort of stuck.

Comment: Isn't this obvious? The translation of a union of open intervals is a union of open intervals...

Answer (score 1):

let $u \in P$
then there exists an open interval

> $I=(u-ε,u+ε)$ s.t. I is contained in P.
> under translation by x this interval becomes:

> $I_x = (u+x-ε,u+x+ε)$ which is contained in P+x.